# Missing bundled JRE in Android Studio for Flutter

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio

Setting up Flutter on MacOS Ventura 13.2 on an M1 MacBook Air. I've installed everything to get `[✓]` except for flutter doctor unable to find a bundled jre in Android Studio. I have found some other questions on this site, but none helped.

```
alan@Alans-MacBook-Air ~ % flutter doctor   
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta), locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Here's the full output of the Android Studio section:

```
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
```

I have java installed:

```
alan@Alans-MacBook-Air ~ % java -version 
java version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)
alan@Alans-MacBook-Air ~ % /usr/libexec/java_home 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I also have my environment setup correctly, I think:

```
alan@Alans-MacBook-Air ~ % echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Some other questions suggest playing with symlinks in the jre folder in the Android Studio install, but I have *no* jre folder in there. There is however a jbr folder, which appears to contain an OpenJDK build. But I don't know how to get flutter to see/use it.

```
alan@Alans-MacBook-Air ~ % /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301, mixed mode)
```

Installed all the components as required in the documentation. I think I've set environment and other parts up correctly.

Answer (score 3):

#### UPDATE 2

While the suggestion in Update 1 would work, this is not a "script" interpreted in real-time, and rather part of the `flutter` binary (if I am not mistaken), so in order for this to work, one would have to compile the `flutter` binary again, I don't know how to do that right now (as I've never used flutter beyond the basics) and I can't certainly do it on my "work machine" where the Corporate eyes forbid everything that is fun.

In other words, use the symlink trick you found [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119325) until the Flutter team releases an updated `flutter` that searches for the correct java Path in the newer versions of Android Studio.

And Jetbrains, please, stop renaming the java location every other year...

#### UPDATE 1

In the flutter sdk, there's a file called: `android_studio.dart`. (well there are various android related files, none "java" related, since it seems like Flutter treats Java as an "android thing" (judging by the fact that all java references and validations or checks are performed in `android_` files).

This file is located in `path/to/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_studio.dart`.

Inside it contains this to calculate the path to java:

```
    final String javaPath = globals.platform.isMacOS ?
        version != null && version.major < 2020 ?
        globals.fs.path.join(directory, 'jre', 'jdk', 'Contents', 'Home') :
        globals.fs.path.join(directory, 'jre', 'Contents', 'Home') :
        globals.fs.path.join(directory, 'jre');
```

In essence, if you add another entry like this:

```
        globals.fs.path.join(directory, 'jbr', 'Contents', 'Home') :
```

So it ends up looking like:

```
    final String javaPath = globals.platform.isMacOS ?
        version != null && version.major < 2020 ?
        globals.fs.path.join(directory, 'jre', 'jdk', 'Contents', 'Home') :
        globals.fs.path.join(directory, 'jre', 'Contents', 'Home') :
        globals.fs.path.join(directory, 'jbr', 'Contents', 'Home') :
        globals.fs.path.join(directory, 'jre');
```

Then you can run `flutter doctor` and it may work.

I also removed the `&& version.major < 2020` part, just to ensure it was always run. Now I see:

```
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
```

So... Two different Android Studio versions, the latest (the one with `jbr` instead of `jre` seems to work fine.

---

In Android Studio Electric Eel, the bundled Java was *moved* to `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home` so you can set your `$JAVA_HOME` to point to that directly.

In Addition, if you're on macOS (as it looks like that's the case) remember macOS uses (for some Apple reason) a binary called `java_home` to set the JAVA installations.

You can find this binary in `/usr/libexec/java_home`.

It seems like the flutter plug-in may be looking for Java under the assumption that it's under the "old" `jre` instead of the "new" `jbr` folder. I don't know if this is hardcoded (and therefore needs a 'patch') or if it just reads the environment variable for JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Jetbrain Toolbox to manage Android Studio?

If so, my solution may work for you.
I'm also using M1Air, Flutter 3.7.0, Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1

cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/{ YOUR_VERSION_OF_ANDROID_STUDIO }/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/

run `ls` and look for `/jbr`

run `sudo ln -s jbr jre` and `flutter doctor`

This solved my problem.

EDIT

Your version of Android Studio can be found at `Jetbrain Toolbox -> Android Studio -> Settings(3 dots on the right) -> Configuration -> Install Location`

[Related Github Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502#issuecomment-1383388490)

Comment: No, not using Jetbrain Toolbox - didn't even know that was a thing. I just went to the Android Studio website and downloaded it from there.